# problem when mounting disk image to iPhone using ideviceimagemounter

Tags: iphone, macos, mount, frida

Hardwares: macOS Big Sur, iPhone XR with IOS16.1.1
Softwares: frida, ideviceimagemounter

I was trying to run 'frida-ps -U' on my mac's terminal, and it said:

> Failed to enumerate processes: this feature requires an IOS Developer Disk Image to be mounted;
> run Xcode briefly or use ideviceimagemounter to mount one manually

Because my MacBook is rather old, Xcode seems not to be a viable option. I tried to use ideviceimagemounter. Following steps from ChatGPT, I installed libimobiledevice using Homebrew, and downloaded DeveloperDiskImage 16.1 (DeveloperDiskImage.dmg and DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature). After all, I ran this command in my terminal:

> ideviceimagemounter -u xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx DeveloperDiskImage.dmg DeveloperDiskImage.dmg.signature

output:

> Uploading ./DeveloperDiskImage.dmg
> done.
> Mounting...
> Error: ImageMountFailed

The error code is 255, what's wrong and how should I deal with that?

I'm sure the device was correctly connected into my mac using USB cable, because I got info when I run 'idevice_id'.
'sudo' was also tried, but didn't work.

Comment: From where did you download the developer disk image? Note that for some iOS versions multiple versions of developer disk images exist, and not all work some times as Apple from time to time release images with bugs.

Comment: I found the cause for that problem, and turning on developer mode in iPhone using certain software can solve that.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your reply. I got the developer disk image from github, and I'm sure it's the right version for now :p

Comment: When using external non-official resources always include a full link at least to the repository you got the disc image from. If the image is the correct version was not my comment. As I wrote Apple several times in the last years released developer disk images that were defect = non-working with the iOS version they were released for.

Comment: I apologize if I'm not providing enough information. The repository is https://github.com/pdso/DeveloperDiskImage. I'm not a professional developer, so sometimes I'll make mistakes that seems stupid.

Comment: No problem, you are a Stackoverflow beginner, if you stay and continue to use SO you soon be familiar with the community and how to write good questions. The 16.1 dmg file you use was released in September 2022 and has the SHA hash `97FC8AE437AB55F630567D51D3CDFF7F1F4CD289`. In October there was an updated version released with SHA-1 `2DFEDC45A9D6A91EC7B6E831F1C3758810443320` which can be found e.g. here: https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images The latter version is also the version included in latest Xcode.

Comment: You are so kind. I'll keep learning, thanks!